# Cannot run Roslyn Samples under VS2015 CTP 3

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

I downloaded Roslyn code and built it successfully within VS2014 CTP 3. I am trying to run the samples that came with the source as part of Samples.sln solution. I can build Samples.sln successfully.

I try running ImplementNotifyPropertyChangedCS sample - I made the project the startup project within the solution and pressed "Start Debugging" menu item. As a result I am getting another VS2014 instance. I open a new project within that instance, create a property and try to refactor the property. I am not getting the option to Implement Notify Property Changed refactoring.

I checked the dependencies of the new instance of the visual studio - it does not depend on ImplementNotifyPropertyChangedCS.dll file. I looked at the output window of the first devenv instance - it seems like that ImplementNotifyPropertyChangedCS.dll was loaded but later was unloaded.

Please help.

Comment: Have you taken a look at: https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/541576 If you place breakpoints within the ImplementNotifyPropertyChanged sample, are they hit? Are they red(filled in) or hollow circles once the new VS instance is running?

Comment: Hey Josh, Thanks for the pointer. I use right mouse menu and choose 'Refactorings'. This should probably work as good as 'Alt+.' - so in my case, I am afraid the problem is different. I am not hitting any breakpoints, and the breakpoints are empty (meaning the corresponding dlls are not loaded or are not used)

Comment: In the ImplementNotifyPropertyChangedCS project's properties (right click -> properties) under "Debug" what are the command line arguments? Also, do any of the samples seem to deploy successfully?

Comment: Command line arguments are /rootsuffix RoslynDev /log. Everything seems to be successfully deployed.